# Getting binary file content instead of UTF-escaped using file.get

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'd like to know if it's possible to get exact binary data using callback from `drive.files.get` method of NodeJS Google API. I know that object returned by calling this API endpoint is a normal `request` object that could be e.g. piped like this:

```
drive.files.get({
  fileId: fileId,
  alt: 'media'
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test'));
```

However I would like to know if it's possible to get binary data from within callback using this syntax:

```
drive.files.get({
  fileId: fileId,
  alt: 'media'
}, function(err, data) {
   // Here I have binary data exposed
});
```

As far as I know, it should be possible to get that kind of data from request during its creation, passing `{encoding: null}` in `request` options object like this:

```
 var requestSettings = {
   method: 'GET',
   url: url,
   encoding: null // This is the important part
};
request(requestSettings, function(err, data) {/.../})`
```

however it seems that Google obscures this configuration object in its library.

So my question is - is it possible to do so without interfering/hacking the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so i found answer that could be useful for others :)
Aforementioned `drive.files.get` method returns Stream object, so it could be directly handled using proper event handlers. Then, buffer parts could be concatenated into one part and sent back in callback like this:

```
var stream = drive.files.get({
  fileId: fileId,
  alt: 'media'
});

// Build buffer
var chunks = [];
stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
  chunks.push(chunk);
});
stream.on('end', () => {
  return cb(null, Buffer.concat(chunks));
});
```

Comment: This helped me solve my problem, thankyou. But I don't really understand why this works where the callback style in your question doesn't work. What encoding is being passed to `data` in the callback ?

Would it be correct to say that [this sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/drive/download.js) will only work for 'utf8' files ?